# Understanding Data Streams and handling their exceptions

Tags: java, data-stream

This is how I write out my file.

```
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filetoreadfrom));       
    FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(filetowriteto);
    DataOutputStream dataStream = new DataOutputStream(fileStream);
    String temp;
    while((temp = read.readLine()) != null){
        String[]arrayTemp = temp.split("\\|");
        dataStream.writeInt(Integer.parseInt(arrayTemp[0]));
        dataStream.writeInt(Integer.parseInt(arrayTemp[1]));
        dataStream.writeUTF(arrayTemp[2]); }
```

So I am trying to write out a binary file and it seems to be working alright. But when I try to read it back it in, I end up getting IOExceptions.

This is how I read in my file.

```
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new  BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("data.bin")));
    int one,two,eight;
    String three,

    while(true){
        one = in.readInt();
        two = in.readInt();
        three = in.readUTF();}
```

I've been looking at the tutorial page for data streams at

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/datastreams.html

and from what I understand in the example it shows catches the end of file condition by catching an EOFException? And  from what I can see from the api, that is a subclass of IOException, which helps me understand as to why I am getting that.

What I don't understand is how to handle it without having an exception occurring. I have tried doing something like in.read() == -1 then break, but to no avail I still get an exception thrown.

Comment: What does the IOException say? Give us the stack trace.

Comment: The thread you posted says it clearly __Notice that DataStreams detects an end-of-file condition by catching EOFException, instead of testing for an invalid return value. All implementations of DataInput methods use EOFException instead of return values__

Comment: @ShashankKadne That statement is incorrect. readLine() returns null at end of stream. It does not throw EOFException.

Comment: Wasn't that method deprecated ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29

Comment: @ShashankKadne Certainly. So?

Comment: Well, I am actually doing a try catch around it so that it catches an IOException e and it just prints out a line whenever it catches it so I know that something was caught.

Comment: @user2677821 For testing purposes, you can do `e.printStackTrace()` instead. Or `System.out.println(e.getMessage())`. But you should be handling an `EOFException` separately as EJP suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The API is already designed. You can't change how it works. Catch the EOFException separately from IOException, close the stream, and break. When you catch IOException, log the error, close the stream, and break.

Comment: So there will be no way that I can avoid getting the exceptions?